# Auto populate form and auto submit with URL Parameters

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms

I want to auto populate the below form with URL parameters for example using a URL like this:

example.co.uk/example.php?acct=wirelesslogicde&pwd=jenkins

I would also like it to Auto submit if possible, how would I go about this??

```
            <form action="http://www.twg.com/logincheck.aspx" method="post" name="login" style="margin-bottom: 0;">
            <p class="readmore" style="margin-bottom: 0;">
            <input name="module" id="module" type="hidden" value="HL"/>
            <input name="page" id="page" type="hidden" value="account.aspx"/>
            <strong>Account:</strong> <br />
            <input name="acct" id="acct" class="contact input" size="12" maxlength="16"/>
            <br />             
            <strong>Password:</strong> <br />
            <input type="password" name="pwd" id="pwd" class="contact input" size="12" maxlength="16"/><br /><br />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="button" value="Login"/>
            </p>
            </form>
```

NEW FORM:

```
    <head>
    <script src="jq.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>

    <form action="http://www.zstats.com/logincheck.aspx" method="post" name="login" style="margin-bottom: 0;" id="zstatslogin">
    <p class="readmore" style="margin-bottom: 0;">
    <input name="module" id="module" type="hidden" value="HL"/>
    <input name="page" id="page" type="hidden" value="account.aspx"/>
    <strong>Account:</strong> <br />
    <input name="acct" id="acct" class="contact input" size="12" maxlength="16" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['acct']; ?>"/>
    <br />             
    <strong>Password:</strong> <br />
    <input type="password" name="pwd" id="pwd" class="contact input" size="12" maxlength="16" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['pwd']; ?>"/><br /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="login" class="button" value="Login"/>
    </p>
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#login").submit();       
    }); 
    </script>
```

Comment: Hi, this URL that you put for the example doesn't work, check it...

Comment: You need to give more information... You want to do it server side in php or client side with js? From what data source will you get the form values? Ajax request? Client cookies? Php session?

Comment: Hi, sorry. I want to email people a link which will automatically fill out this form, so the values in the URL will be put there by me. I want the easiest solution really it doesn't matter if that is front end or back end.

Comment: after enter the account and password ,it needs to be auto submit. isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could do the autosubmit by using jQuery

```
$('#some_form_id').onLoad(function(){
$.Post('form_target',{parameters:values});
});
```

and for the populate you can add

```
<input name="acct" id="acct" class="contact input" size="12" maxlength="16" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['acc']; ?>"/>
<input type="password" name="pwd" id="pwd" class="contact input" size="12" maxlength="16" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['pwd']; ?>"/>
```

Comment: The populate part is working well thank you, but the autosubmit isn't doing anything. :(

Comment: $('#some_form_id').onLoad(function(){
$.Post('form_target',{parameters:values}, function(data) {alert(data)});
}); you can use it to see what is the submit returning

Answer (score 1):

```
        <form action="http://www.twg.com/logincheck.aspx" method="post" id="login" name="login" style="margin-bottom: 0;">
           <p class="readmore" style="margin-bottom: 0;">
              <input name="module" id="module" type="hidden" value="HL"/>
              <input name="page" id="page" type="hidden" value="account.aspx"/>
              <strong>Account:</strong> <br />
              <input name="acct" id="acct" class="contact input"  value="<?=$_GET['acct']?>" size="12" maxlength="16"/>
              <br />             
              <strong>Password:</strong> <br />
              <input type="password" name="pwd" id="pwd" class="contact input"  value="<?=$_GET['pwd']?>" size="12" maxlength="16"/><br /><br />
              <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="button" value="Login"/>
           </p>
        </form>
```

Use `$_GET` to get the values from `URL`.

For auto submit use, Make sure you have jquery plugin loaded before you use the following script. If you don't have JQuery added get it from [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) and include the file like any other `javascript` file in your `<head>` section of `HTML` document.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#login").submit();       
});
```

Comment: Brilliant, it nearly worked for some reason size= was being put in the form fields aswell. Also any way of getting it to auto submit?

Comment: Hmm thanks for the help! Auto Submit not quite working though!

Comment: do you have jquery added before you call tat auto submit script ?

Comment: use your chrome developer tools to see if you get any javascript errors.

Comment: Will do I have tried adding the submit code both in the header and below

Comment: Sure but that is my whole page I haven't added anything else yet;) http://pastebin.com/e685m8sP

Comment: okay!! your `<form>` has `id` attribute `id="zstatslogin"` and in the javascript you have it like `login` so change one of those.. and i belive that your `jq.js` is JQuery plugin!!

Comment: OK I have changes the JQuery to the correct one hosted by Google. but I am getting this error: Uncaught TypeError: Property 'submit' of object #<HTMLFormElement> is not a function. here is a new pastebin: http://pastebin.com/syAmUHKz

Comment: change your ` <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="button" value="Login"/>` to ` <input type="submit" name="submitlogin" id="submitlogin" class="button" value="Login"/>`

Comment: dont name any of ur `HTML` elements with reserved keywords. It will cause unexpected errors...

Answer (score 0):

You can do this either by php using for example:

```
<input name="acct" id="acct" class="contact input" size="12" type="text" value=="<?php echo $_GET['acct'];?>" maxlength="16"/>
```

or using javascript, which would be a bit more complex, look at the window.location.search to filter down querystrings..

ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location

Comment: This is BAD! You should NEVER show user-input without sanatizing it, in a response. XSS, SQL, lot of things a hacker could do ...