# Auto Submit Form not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Using this open source file:
     https://raw.github.com/openemr/openemr/master/interface/billing/sl_eob_search.php

I want to do auto submit form and is not responding.

I am using as reference this [Auto populate form and auto submit with URL Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12385524/auto-populate-form-and-auto-submit-with-url-parameters)

which is what I would like to do - submit URL parameters but is not working.

**REVISED**

1st I added an id to the `<form>`, left the "values" on the textbox unchanged as I'm passing those values via URL.

```
<form method='post' action='sl_eob_search.php' id='search_invoice'
  enctype='multipart/form-data'>
  .
  .
  .
  <td>
    <input type='text' name='form_pid' size='10'
      value='<?php echo $_POST['form_pid']; ?>'
      title='<?php xl("Patient chart ID","e"); ?>'>
  </td>
  <td>
    <?php xl('Encounter:','e'); ?>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type='text' name='form_encounter' size='10'
      value='<?php echo $_POST['form_encounter']; ?>'
      title='<?php xl("Encounter number","e"); ?>'>
  </td>
  .
  .
  .
  <td>
    <input type='submit' name='form_search' id='search'
      value='<?php xl("Search","e"); ?>'>
  </td>
  .
  .
  .
</form>
```

**SUBMIT BUTTON**

I added an "id" attribute, and after the `</form>` closed:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#search").submit();       
  }); 
</script>
```

It didn't work... then went and got the form `id`:

```
document.forms['search_invoice'].submit();
```

And nothing happens.

Comment: Please paste your relevant code where you are facing error

Comment: See the accepted answer to the question you linked, there you can see you need to select the form and call sumbit on it. Did you try that? I have been unable to find it in the code you linked. Show us what did you try, how is it "not working" (does it produce an error, or what?).

Comment: Revised my question and no errors it just won't show anything - like if you manually click "Search"

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by using click instead of submit!!

```
$(document).ready(function(){$("#search").click();});
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You have used the `id` of the submit field (`search`):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#search").submit();       
  }); 
</script>
```

You should use the `id` of the form instead:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#search_invoice").submit();       
  }); 
</script>
```

Comment: I did use the form name but it did not do the trick :(