# How to fill PHP form with data from URL?

Tags: php, post

I have a short sample php code above:

```
<HTML XMLns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xHTML"> 
<head> 
<title>Check for perfect palindrome</title>
</head> 
<body>
     <h1>Check for perfect palindrome</h1>
    <form method="post">
     <label for="stringInput">String:</label><input type="text" id="stringInput" name="stringInput"><br/>
     <br/><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Check"/>
    </form>
</body> 
<?php
if(isset($_POST['stringInput']))
{
    $string = $_POST['stringInput'];
    if ($string =="")
    {
        echo "Please fill the form";
    } else if ($string == strrev($string))
    {
        echo "You entered: <b>'$string'</b> is a perfect palindrome.";
    } else 
    {
        echo "You entered: <b>'$string'</b> is NOT a perfect palindrome.";
    }
}
?>
</HTML>
```

Imagine that the code is saved under file sample.php and located at localhost/sample.php.

I want to fill the form and trigger the submit button through this link:

`localhost/sample.php?stringInput=abc&submit=Check`

How can I do that? Thanks for help.

I need to use POST method because the actual form has many inputs not just one and I want to know how it will work with POST. And using PHP only if possible. (Javascript, jQuery are not the first choices). Cheers.

This is a good example to demonstrate what I need.

http://image.online-convert.com/convert-to-jpg?external_url=jhjhj&width=333

I tried GET method and the form doesn't display value.

Comment: If you want the link that you're showing below your code snippet, then change the form method to `GET` and reference the `$_GET` super global in PHP. Post variables are not appended to the url as a query string. They are sent in the request body...

Comment: Use form method as get instead of post

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Auto populate form and auto submit with URL Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12385524/auto-populate-form-and-auto-submit-with-url-parameters)

Comment: I need to use POST method because the actual form has many inputs not just one.

Comment: @devlincarnate I need to know how it works with PHP if possible before trying with Javascript or jQuery. Thanks.

Comment: @VietNguyen - There is an answer in that other question that is PHP only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

You can assign your post values to variables & echo them in your input.

```
   <HTML XMLns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xHTML"> 
    <head> 
    <title>Check for perfect palindrome</title>
    </head> 
    <body>
    <?php
    $string = "";
    if(isset($_POST['stringInput']))
    {
        $string = $_POST['stringInput'];

        if ($string =="")
        {
            echo "Please fill the form";
        } else if ($string == strrev($string) )
        {
            echo "You entered: <b>'$string'</b> is a perfect palindrome.";
        } else 
        {
            echo "You entered: <b>'$string'</b> is NOT a perfect palindrome.";
        }
    }
    ?>

         <h1>Check for perfect palindrome</h1>
        <form method="post">
         <label for="stringInput">String:</label><input type="text" id="stringInput" name="stringInput" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['stringInput'];?>"><br/>
         <br/><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Check" />
        </form>
    </body> 

    </HTML>
```

Comment: but he have post method in form

Comment: @VietNguyen try now it ll work in both cases check $_REQUEST https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_superglobals.asp

Comment: @Omi Thanks mate. The form field is filled now with ?stringInput=abc but the button is not triggered with &submit=Check part.

Comment: you need to do same with submit `value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['your input name'];?>`" & same for other

Comment: ops, I tried but it just changed the button Value. It should act like the button is pressed. Please help. Thanks, mate. @Omi

Comment: do you have any css class which makes button like pressed

Comment: Thanks for the help. It has done so far with javascript for the auto submit feature. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to include the parameters in the URL you cannot use POST

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_(HTTP)):

> the POST request method requests that a web server accept the data enclosed in the body of the request message

Whereas in a GET request (from [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp)):

> the query string is sent in the URL of a GET request

Comment: This is a good example to demonstrate what I need. 

http://image.online-convert.com/convert-to-jpg?external_url=jhjhj&width=333

I tried GET method and the form doesn't display value.

Comment: I know what you mean, but you need to use a GET request instead. See my updated response.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will try to fix my work with that. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong http method instead of **POST** you should use **GET**

> "Note that the query string (name/value pairs) is sent in the URL of a
>   GET request"

Check more about these two methods here: [POST vs GET](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp)

Comment: This is a good example to demonstrate what I need. 

http://image.online-convert.com/convert-to-jpg?external_url=jhjhj&width=333

I tried GET method and the form doesn't display value.